# Dynamically Uncheck All Checkbox's From Container Using A Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-select

fiddle - http://jsbin.com/OruFonU/1/edit
completed fiddle (for anyone who's in the same boat) - http://jsbin.com/OruFonU/15/edit

I'm trying to uncheck all checkbox's based upon the text in a texbox. If the textbox's value is equal to "Uncheck All" I want all checkbox's unchecked inside it's container div. (not all completely, just all inside the visible container)

I've tried the following but no luck.

```
.removeAttr('checked');
.attr('checked', false);
.prop('checked', false);
.is(':checked', false);
```

Here's the full JQuery/Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', 'checked');
    $('.show').hide();
    $('.number-1').show();

  $(".show-nums").on('load change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    if( $("." + val) && $("." + val).length ){
      //check if there is a selector that corresponds to the value of the dropdown
      $('.show').hide();
      $("." + val).show();
    }
  });

  $(".search").on('keyup change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val === "Uncheck All") {
      $('.number-1 input[type=checkbox], .number-2 input[type=checkbox], .number-3 input[type=checkbox], .number-4 input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

If anyone can help me with this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest using val.toLowerCase() so you don't need to write exactly "Uncheck All"

Comment: I just need to write "un" and I can enter  "Uncheck All" from the datalist that acts as a sort of autocomplete. As seen in JQuery UI

Comment: Yeah thats true, but if the user wants to write it instead of clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your code would work. The thing that fails is the the selector for the inputs. You can fix that by fixing the selector for example juste use `input[type=text]`.

There are other things you could improve, I have updated your jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/OruFonU/13/edit

you can dramatically simplify your code (and make it more readable) by doing this:

```
  $(".show-nums").on('load change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    $('.show').hide();

    if( $("." + val) && $("." + val).length ){
      //check if there is a selector that corresponds to the value of the dropdown
      $("." + val).show();
    }
  });
```

side note: `form` tags are not allowed inside of paragraphs (`p`). Since inline elements are not allowed inside a `p` elements, the browser just assumes that the `p` tag was not closed and close it by him self. This is the result, and this is why your selector is not working:

[image: dom result]

The forms are not inside the P elements anymore.

If you have to stick to your HTML structure I would suggest you set the `.number-n` on the form tag.

Comment: I just learned about the paragraph's not being made to use as flows. Thanks for the help btw. I +1 your post. Much simpler, easier to read, and I learned a new handler.

Comment: @mikethedj4 edited my post you could set the class on the form tag, if you need to stick to this HTML structure.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you wrap `form` inside `p` tag. Try to put your form inside `div` and it should work as expected

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rKNSn/)

Comment: I'm confused as to why p or div make a difference in this. I see the difference, but I'm confused as to why this happens.

Comment: @mikethedj4 according to specs P tag isn't allowed to contain any element which is not an inline element. FORM is a block one. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xhtml-modularization-20010410/abstract_modules.html#s%5Ftextmodule for details.

Comment: @mikethedj4 It's because `<p>` is only allowed to contain text or 'inline' tags. However a `<form>` counts as 'block' content not as 'inline' content

Comment: I thought I was annoyed before now I'm like, "agh all because of a paragraph" lol. Anyway thank you all. This has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you problem is that this selector:

```
  $('.number-1 input[type=checkbox], .number-2 input[type=checkbox], .number-3      input[type=checkbox], .number-4 input[type=checkbox]')
```

returns [] empty.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I only want to select the input type checkbox's inside of those containers. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Start by reconstructing your html as suggested by @felix.  notice that in your demo the closing tags of the p appear in red.  notice also that $('.number-2 > form') returns empty. Change the p tags to div. see working example : http://jsbin.com/OruFonU/5/

Answer (score 0):

just use $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

```
$(".search").on('keyup change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val === "Uncheck All") {
       $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

I have used this in your fiddle and it works fine.

If you want to find specifically then you can use like this

```
   $('.number-1').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked'); 
   $('.number-2').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
   $('.number-3').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
   $('.number-4').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

You can also apply any loop here.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I only want to select the input type checkbox's inside of it's containers. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @mikethedj4 I have changed my answer please check if it resolve your inquiry.